# I wonder if I can compare two array items without an if-statement

Tags: javascript, loops

given that I want to compare two equally long arrays, if they have the same value at the same position, can I do this with a loop but with NO IF STATEMENT?

This code works

```
function twoArrays(arr, arr2) {
    var count = 0;
    arr.forEach (function(item, index){
        if(arr[item, index]===arr2[item, index]) {
            count++
        }
    })
    return count
}

twoArrays([2,3,4,6],[2,1,4,5])
// return 2
```

But how about something without an if statement?

EDIT: every time there is a match the counter goes up one.
Bonus: can I use other loops? (Which)?

Comment: why don't you want to use a if ?

Comment: Just wondering.

Comment: You want to increment a counter on some *condition*, that requires a *conditional* (ie. an `if`)

Comment: Thanks .... again. I am just wondering.

Comment: It's very unnecessary two downgrade the question. I learn javascript and I am curious to explore various paths. If anything you should up the curiosity and not curb it.

Comment: curiosity is good, but as you worded it I read it as a twisted homework (which SO doesn't want to answer), that's may be why you got downvoted

Comment: The homework is to solve the task (any way). I was just wondering if there is anything beyond the obvious. Too bad that some are offended by any means. My advice to them: if in doubt, assume that the learner has nothing bad in mind and is not lazy per se.

Comment: just do `count += arr1[i] === arr2[i]`

Comment: @georg - FWIW, I recommend undeleting your answer with that. Definitely should be listed, I can't believe I missed it out of my list. Particularly combined with `reduce` `return arr1.reduce(function(count, item, index) { return count + (item === arr2[index]); }, 0);` (or the ES2015+ version, but OP seemed to be sticking with ES5.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to avoid an `if` statement, though it's not clear why you want to.

The first is to use `filter`:

```
var count = arr1.filter(function(item, index) { return item === arr2[index]; }).length;
```

...but it creates an unnecessary array (temporarily).

Live Example:

```js
function twoArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(function(item, index) { return item === arr2[index]; }).length;
}
console.log(twoArrays([2,3,4,6],[2,1,4,5]));
```

The second is to use `&&`:

```
var count = 0;
arr1.forEach(function(item, index) { item === arr2[index] && ++count; });
```

...but it's really just an `if` in disguise. `&&` evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that operand is falsy, takes that falsy value as its result (which is then thrown away in the above); if the value of the left-hand operand is truthy, `&&` evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that as its result. That means side effects in the right-hand operand only happen if the left-hand operand's value is truthy, which is why `++count` works.

Live Example:

```js
function twoArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    var count = 0;
    arr1.forEach(function(item, index) { item === arr2[index] && ++count; });
    return count;
}
console.log(twoArrays([2,3,4,6],[2,1,4,5]));
```

Similarly, you could use the conditional operator, either with `forEach`:

```
var count = 0;
arr1.forEach(function(item, index) { count += item === arr2[index] ? 1 : 0; });
```

...or with `reduce`:

```
var count = arr1.reduce(function(acc, item, index) { return acc + (item === arr2[index] ? 1 : 0); }, 0);
```

Live Example:

```js
function twoArraysA(arr1, arr2) {
    var count = 0;
    arr1.forEach(function(item, index) { count += item === arr2[index] ? 1 : 0; });
    return count;
}
console.log(twoArraysA([2,3,4,6],[2,1,4,5]));

function twoArraysB(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.reduce(function(acc, item, index) { return acc + (item === arr2[index] ? 1 : 0); }, 0);
}
console.log(twoArraysB([2,3,4,6],[2,1,4,5]));
```

...but again, there's still conditional logic in there.

---

I don't recommend any of them. Just use the `if`. :-)

Comment: OK ... I see that there are ways under certain conditions but they require lots of skills